# What actions earn points in Dominion?

Tags: league-of-legends

So League of Legends currently has its new Dominion game mode open sporadically for testing, and I've been checking it out. It's pretty neat; one of the biggest changes from the traditional MOBA-style "Classic" mode is the advent of a scorecard.

I've noticed that certain actions give me points. Some of these, "Kill", "Kill-Assist", "Point Captured", etc. are self-explanatory.

Others, like "Martyr" are less-so.

What are all the possible ways to earn points in Dominion, and how many does each action earn?

Comment: Martyr is apparently when you die protecting a capture point (and you are alone ?). It gives 40 points.

Comment: The call it their "Renown System", but I was unable to find a listing of all the possible points.

Comment: @Dalshim - I've had Martyr award 20 and 30 points also, so dunno what affects it.

Comment: Damn. I didn't manage to get martyr again in the games I just played. Did you find out when it occures ?

Comment: There is assist too... if you give someone a heal, a speed boost anything that can relate to a buff you get +2 for assist

Comment: @RavenDreamer I believe martyr's points also vary based on how many enemies you die defending the point to.  But that's speculation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can't guarantee that this list is complete yet, but here's all the awards I know of:

- Kills & assists on a point grant double award (30/15 kill, 10/5 assist).
- Point capture & neutralize are each +40 award.
- Standing on or near a friendly point gives +5 award for point defense.
- Channeling a point when neutralization or capture occurs grants a reward. If you cancel or are interrupted before your teammates complete a neutralization or capture, you get an assist reward (+20).
- Interrupting an enemy channel grants +5 award.
- Additional awards are granted for multi-kills & shutting down killing sprees.
- Applying a friendly effect to an allied champion grants a supported ally award for +2 points.
- Picking up a health pack grants +2 award.
- Capturing the relic grants an award - Relic Hunter - and +3 points.
- Capturing a quest point grants 20 points to the entire team.
- Dying near a channeling ally who subsequently completes the capture grants a martyr award. (variable)
- Dying shortly after interrupting enemy channel on a friendly point grants a martyr award. (variable)
- Minion kills grant 2 points each.

Comment: Your second bullet point is wrong. Anyone who's channeling gets the points for neutralize / capture. Capture assist happens when you're on the point and have *been* channeling, but aren't when it turns over.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Thanks for the heads up. Edited to fix.

Comment: You get +2 points for picking up a health pack.

Comment: Whats the **Point** of getting all these points?

Comment: @Ender Har har. Dominion points basically a substitute for KDA+CS; they are an approximate metric for your personal contribution to the team.